# Display Worksheet Names in HTMLBody

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a macro that drafts an email. For the `.HTMLBody` field I would like to display all of the names of the worksheets in my current workbook in the following way in the email body.

Apples

Pears

Oranges

Grapes

Bananas

The following code will populate the body of my email with one line:
ApplesPearsOrangesGrapesBananas

My full code is not shown because some of the hardcoded lines contain confidential info.

```vb
Dim wks As Worksheet, strName As String

For Each wks In Worksheets
    strName = strName & wks.Name
Next

msg = strName
.HTMLBody = strName
```

Comment: `strName = strName & wks.Name & "<br>"`

Comment: This is such a simple and elegant solution that did not occur to my overworked brain. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### List Worksheet Names

- You could use the following function:

```vb
Function ListWorksheetNames( _
    ByVal wb As Workbook, _
    ByVal Delimiter As String) _
As String
    If wb Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If wb.Worksheets.Count = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsNames As String
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        wsNames = wsNames & ws.Name & Delimiter
    Next ws
    wsNames = Left(wsNames, Len(wsNames) - Len(Delimiter)) ' remove last

    ListWorksheetNames = wsNames

End Function
```

- In your code you would utilize it in the following way:

  ```
  Dim msg As String
  msg = ListWorksheetNames(ThisWorkbook, vbLf)
  ```

  where `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook containing this code.
- If you need empty lines in between, you could use `vbLf & vbLf`.